# How to find a class with certain background color in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="common" style="bacground-color:rgb(255,255,255)"></div>
<div class="common" style="bacground-color:rgb(140,255,255)"></div>
```

here i have to find class common whose background color is rgb(255,255,255).

```
$(".common").each(function(){
if($(this).css("bacground-color") == "rgb(255,255,255)"){
alert ('this')
}
});
```

This is correct method ?

Please help .

Comment: What you have tried so far ?

Comment: move inline css into CSS class and find by class name

Comment: .common[background-color="rgb(255,255,255)"]

Comment: @Jonasw won't work, as there is no `background-color` attribute.

Comment: please check now

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Selecting elements based on color is generally not a very good idea, as it can vary what browsers return etc. Try to find a better way

Comment: but what i will do if all background color are written as inline in rgb format and i don't have other option ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this its working**
  you can check here https://jsfiddle.net/surendra786/dt3r7x97/
you have mistaken in background spelling 'bacground' and also give the spaces b/w color code like this  rgb(255, 255, 255)

```
$(".common").each(function(){
 if($(this).css("background-color") == "rgb(255, 255, 255)"){
  alert ('this')
}
```

});

plz up if its working

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS selector `.common[style~="bacground-color:rgb(255,255,255)"]` (`~=` will select attribute containing the following) here is example in jQuery:

```js
$(function() {
 console.log($('.common[style~="bacground-color:rgb(255,255,255)"]').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="common" style="bacground-color:rgb(255,255,255)">1</div>
<div class="common" style="bacground-color:rgb(140,255,255)">2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think bacground-color is misspelled.

It should be:

```
<div class="common" style="background-color:rgb(255,255,255)"></div>
```

Second the css selector is backgroundColor.

```
$('.common').each(function(i, e) 
{     
   if ( $(e).css("backgroundColor")=="rgb(255, 255, 255)" )
    {
        alert(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('div').each(function(){
    var a = jQuery(this).css('background-color');

    if ( a.indexOf('255, 255, 255') > -1 ){ //spaces are important (255,255,255) won't work.

        console.log('bbb')
    }
})
```